# How to refer a series a closed excel workbooks from an open excel work sheet

Tags: excel

I have a series of files save with names A,B,C,D. These are the items of my first row in the sheet I am working in. Now I need to refer the data from file'A' when I am working on the row that has 'A' in the first column.

I wanted to see if there is an option like VLOOKUP for different excel workbooks?

Thank you
Naga

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the file location, file name and the sheet name in order to do this.

Use the syntax in the example below;

```
=VLOOKUP(F3,'C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop[test1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A6,1,FALSE)
```

Then Excel will open a file explorer box and have you select the correct file.  Select it and then your formula should work.

See this link for more information:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f

Comment: Hi,i have multiple files to be referred. Not one like 'test1.xlsx'.When I lookup F3 it should refer test1 and F4 it should refer test2 and so on..